# A problem implementing Dependency Injection and Interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface

I'm trying to get an idea of dependency injection and interfaces but I'm running into a weird problem.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5vfcd0

I have an Interface and a Model that implements that interface:

```
public class FileModel : IFileModel
{
    public string Filepath {get;set;}
}

public interface IFileModel
{
    string Filepath {get;set;}
}
```

I also have a FileProcessor class, that processes objects that implement the IFileModel interface:

```
public class FileProcessor
{
    private static IFileModel _file;

    public FileProcessor(IFileModel file)
    {
        _file = file;
    }

    public List<IFileModel> ProcessFiles(List<string> filepaths)
    {
        List<IFileModel> output = new List<IFileModel>();

        foreach(string path in filepaths)
        {
            _file.Filepath = path;
            output.Add(_file);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

In my Main() method, I create a list of dummy filepaths. I then create an instance of the FileProcessor and I give a new instance of a FileModel as the parameter to the constructor of the FileProcessor. I do this in order to specify to the FileProcessor what kind of files I'm about to process.

I call the ProcessFiles() method of the FileProcessor instance, which takes the list of filepaths as a parameter. ProcessFiles() loops through the filepaths and creates a list of IFileModel objects and returns that list.

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> filepaths = new List<string>();
    filepaths.Add("path1");
    filepaths.Add("path2");
    filepaths.Add("path3");
    filepaths.Add("path4");
    filepaths.Add("path5");

    FileProcessor fileProcessor = new FileProcessor(new FileModel());

    List<IFileModel> files = fileProcessor.ProcessFiles(filepaths); 

    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.Filepath);
    }
}
```

My assumption would be, that in the end of the Main() method, I'd have a List where each object in that list would have a different filepath.

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Filepath);
}

output:
path1
path2
path3
path4
path5
```

Instead, each object in the list returned by ProcessFiles() method is populated with the filepath of the **last** filepath that the method looped through. The result is this:

```
path5
path5
path5
path5
path5
```

I created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem. https://dotnetfiddle.net/5vfcd0

If I instanciate a new FileModel in the ProcessFiles() method, it works as intended. But I don't want the FileProcessor to be dependant on a specific implementation of IFileModel.

```
public List<IFileModel> ProcessFiles(List<string> filepaths)
{
    List<IFileModel> output = new List<IFileModel>();

    foreach(string path in filepaths)
    {
        _file = new FileModel(); // dependency
        _file.Filepath = path;
        output.Add(_file);
    }

    return output;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I fix this implementation, so that FileProcessor is not dependant on any specific class that implements the IFileModel interface?

Comment: That's because you only have 1 object, and it has state, which you change every iteration of the loop. If your intention is to a) not have to construct new such FileModel objects in the loop because you then need to handle the dependencies, and b) still be allowed to get multiple independent FileModel objects, then instead of taking a dependency on the FileModel object, take a dependency on a factory that can be asked to produce FileModel objects on demand, given a path.

Comment: Create a factory. its single responsibility will be to create IFileModel based on path

Comment: In other words, take a dependency on `IFileModelFactory` which has a method like `IFileModel Create(string path);`, which internally constructs the right object in the right way.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and help. I marked Johnathan's answer as correct, because he provided some code samples. I would upvote Lasse's answer but I do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: Why do you hide `FileModel` behind an abstraction anywat? `FileModel` seems like a data-centric object with no behavior. It doesn't seem very useful to hide it behind an abstraction in your case. Instead I would suggest letting `ProcessFiles` just create new `FileModel` instances itself; that severely simplifies your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently passing one instance of `FileModel` to your `FileProcessor` class and adding it to the list 5 times.

Each time, you are updating the `Filepath` of the same instance.

What you probably want to do, is inject a factory method:

```
public class FileProcessor
{
    private static Func<IFileModel> _fileFactory;

    public FileProcessor(Func<IFileModel> fileFactory)
    {
        _fileFactory = fileFactory;
    }

    public List<IFileModel> ProcessFiles(List<string> filepaths)
    {
        List<IFileModel> output = new List<IFileModel>();

        foreach(string path in filepaths)
        {
            var file = _fileFactory();
            file.Filepath = path;
            output.Add(file);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Then call as follows:

```
var fileProcessor = new FileProcessor(() => new FileModel());
```

Or even better, create an interface for your factory:

```
interface IFileModelFactory
{
    FileModel CreateModel();
}
```

Implement:

```
class FileModelFactory
{
    public FileModel CreateModel() => new FileModel();
}
```

And inject:

```
public class FileProcessor
{
    private static IFileModelFactory _fileFactory;

    public FileProcessor(IFileModelFactory fileFactory)
    {
        _fileFactory = fileFactory;
    }

    public List<IFileModel> ProcessFiles(List<string> filepaths)
    {
        List<IFileModel> output = new List<IFileModel>();

        foreach(string path in filepaths)
        {
            var file = _fileFactory.CreateModel();
            file.Filepath = path;
            output.Add(file);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Marked as the answer because of the code examples.

I do like the FactoryMethod approach for it's simplicity, and because it taught me to actually use Func<> for the first time.

Although I agree, doing the interface/implementation of the factory would probably be more "correct".